# Is there an Office 2010 Black theme for VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, themes, color-scheme

I installed Office 2010 and switched it to the Black theme... I really like it but now my Visual Studio looks bad beside it.

Does anyone know of a good implementation of the Office 2010 Black Theme for Visual Studio 2010?

[I already have http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme and it doesn't match Office at all (no, I know it wasn't supposed to)]

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked http://studiostyl.es/ ?

Comment: Sadly that only appears to cover the actual editor window itself (I'm happy with what I have) rather than the window chrome (menus, borders, lists, etc) which is what the Office 2010 theme changes.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378?SRC=Home), then go to Theme -> Customize Colors and create new scheme with dark colors. You may copy existing theme and recolor it

Comment: Yes, I was hoping there might already be a suitable version rather than spending hours trying to create it myself.

Comment: Isn't this good enough? http://www.nerdpad.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/vs2010_Gray.png

Comment: As I said in my question it's not, it doesn't look at all like office 2k10.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this theme to your liking:

http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme